# How can I prevent wide equation having too large vertical space?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I have a list of equations of which one is probably slightly larger than a certain threshold. This somehow results in the equation being given more vertical space above it than the others.

What can I do to make this equation behave like all the others in terms of vertical space above?

I am using XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.4.29).

Minimal working example follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{e \in \mathcal{E}}\sum_{f \in \mathcal{F}} k_{ef} + \sum_{d \in \mathcal{D}} x_{abcd} + T_{abc} \leq 1 \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
w_{abc} \leq \sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} g_{abcg} \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
X_{abcd} - \Delta^{+}_{abcd} + \Delta^{-}_{abcd} - x_{abcd} = 0 \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}, d \in \mathcal{D}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
Y_{abcdef} - \Delta^{-}_{abcdef} + \Delta^{+}_{abcdef} - y_{abcdef} = 0 \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}, d \in \mathcal{D}, e \in \mathcal{E}, f \in \mathcal{F}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following output. Note the excessive vertical space between (3) and (4).

[image]

Comment: Don't leave empty lines in between the equation environments. Then there is no odd spacing.

Comment: @HarishKumar That is a great help indeed. However, I now have a different spacing issue because there are some `subequations` environments in my list which exhibit the same spacing problem when removing the empty lines.

Comment: You should use a `gather` environment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use a single `gather` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package) instead of four separate `equation` environments. To keep the distance between equations 3 and 4 roughly equal to that between equations 2 and 3, you could insert a `\vphantom` ("vertical phantom") in the third equation, as is shown in the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "gather" environment
\usepackage{fullpage} %für inch Abstände??

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\sum_{e \in \mathcal{E}}\sum_{f \in \mathcal{F}} k_{ef} 
   + \sum_{d \in \mathcal{D}} x_{abcd} + T_{abc} \leq 1 
   \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}\\
w_{abc} \leq \sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} g_{abcg} 
   \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}\\
X_{abcd} - \Delta^{+}_{abcd} + \Delta^{-}_{abcd} - x_{abcd} = 0 
   \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}, 
   d \in \mathcal{D} \vphantom{\sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}}}\\ % <-- note the "\vphantom"
Y_{abcdef} - \Delta^{-}_{abcdef} + \Delta^{+}_{abcdef} - y_{abcdef} = 0 
   \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}, 
   d \in \mathcal{D}, e \in \mathcal{E}, f \in \mathcal{F}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that my actual list of equations is quite long and should span several pages. Unfortunately, the gather environment doesn't break when it should, it is always displayed on one page.

Comment: Never mind, I found the option to allow page breaks within a `gather` environment. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris - Just for future readers of this posting: The instruction that allows page breaks within a `gather` environment is called `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the `gather` environment, from `amsmath`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \sum_{e \in \mathcal{E}}\sum_{f \in \mathcal{F}} k_{ef} + \sum_{d \in \mathcal{D}} x_{abcd} + T_{abc} \leq 1 \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}\\
  w_{abc} \leq \sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} g_{abcg} \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}\\
  X_{abcd} - \Delta^{+}_{abcd} + \Delta^{-}_{abcd} - x_{abcd} = 0 \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}, d \in \mathcal{D}\\[1.5ex]
  Y_{abcdef} - \Delta^{-}_{abcdef} + \Delta^{+}_{abcdef} - y_{abcdef} = 0 \quad \forall a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}, c \in \mathcal{C}, d \in \mathcal{D}, e \in \mathcal{E}, f \in \mathcal{F}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]